# Meteor + Angular2 - Cannot find name 'Router'

Tags: angular, meteor, ionic2, router

I'm trying to mix Meteor and Angular2 to one app with this tutorial [enter link description here](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/meteor/setup)

Everything works without meteor but when it's running with meteor I got 2 errors :

> Cannot find name 'Router'.

And

> Cannot find name 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot'

.

The problem is I did "meteor npm install --save @angular/router" it was installed but nothing changed :/

My package.json

```
    {
    "name": "meteor-test",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "meteor run",
        "desktop": "meteor-desktop -p 4000"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.2.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.2.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.6",
        "@angular/core": "4.2.6",
        "@angular/forms": "4.2.6",
        "@angular/http": "4.2.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.6",
        "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.6",
        "@angular/router": "4.3.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
        "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
        "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
        "ionic-angular": "^3.5.0",
        "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
        "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
        "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
        "meteor-rxjs": "^0.4.7",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
        "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/meteor": "^1.4.2",
        "@types/meteor-accounts-phone": "0.0.5",
        "@types/underscore": "^1.8.1",
        "meteor-desktop": "^0.8.0",
        "meteor-typings": "^1.4.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in tsconfig.json file !

You have to remove this line :

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that these are the classes that you should import:

```
import {
  RouterModule,
  Routes,
  ActivatedRoute
} from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: I'm using @angular/router v3.1.x so is not in the package